# how to initialize object of class with two pointers?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

Ok, so i know this is kind of basic, but i can't understand what i'm doing wrong here.
this is the class:

```
class numar_complex {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const numar_complex& numar_complex);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, numar_complex& numar_complex);

private:
    double* p_real;
    double* p_imaginar;

public:
    //constructor, destructor:
    numar_complex()
    {

        double* p_real{ new double(0.0) };

        double* p_imaginar{ new double(0.0) };

        cout << "constructor" << endl;
    }
    numar_complex(const numar_complex& nr)
    {
        if (p_real != nullptr) {
            p_real = nullptr;
            delete p_real;
        }
        p_real = new double(*nr.p_real);
        if (p_imaginar != nullptr) {
            p_imaginar = nullptr;
            delete p_imaginar;
        }
        p_imaginar = new double(*nr.p_imaginar);
        cout << "copy constructor " << endl;
    }
    ~numar_complex()
    {
        p_real = nullptr;
        delete p_real;
        p_imaginar = nullptr;

        delete p_imaginar;

        cout << "destructor" << endl;
    }

    // getteri:

    double get_p_real()
    {
        return *p_real;
    }
    double get_p_imaginar()
    {
        return *p_imaginar;
    }
    //setteri:

    void set_p_real(double x)
    {
        p_real = nullptr;
        delete p_real;
        p_real = new double(x);
    }
    void set_p_imaginar(double x)
    {
        p_imaginar = nullptr;
        delete p_imaginar;
        p_imaginar = new double(x);
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const numar_complex& numar_complex)
    {
        if (*numar_complex.p_imaginar >= 0) {
            out << *numar_complex.p_real << "+" << *numar_complex.p_imaginar << "*i \n";
        }
        else if (*numar_complex.p_imaginar < 0) {
            out << *numar_complex.p_real << *numar_complex.p_imaginar << "*i \n";
        }

        return out;
    }
```

and for some reason, when i simply declare an object of this class, as

```
numar complex x; 
cout << x;
```

it crashes (memory problem); however, if i use the setters/getters, the problem doesn't appear anymore. in the case of

```
numar complex x; 
x.set_p_real(1); 
x.set_p_imaginar(1); 
cout << x;
```

will result in 1 + 1i;
PS: If i don't use the setters to initialize values, the getters will also result in a crash.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but perhaps consider using [std::complex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)?  Or at least another library class?

Comment: In your constructor, you create *local* variables, which are discarded as soon as constructor finishes. Member variables are not initialized by this constructor.

Comment: Why do you even use pointers?

Comment: You need to call delete on a pointer, THEN set it to nullptr.

Comment: Also, in copy constructor you don't need to remove previous existing state, because there could be no previous state. It's a constructor, you are in the process of creating new object. Deleting of previous state would be needed in copy assignment operator.

Comment: There's nothing in the shown code that requires the use of pointers. It only makes the shown code twice as bigger, and more bug prone, than it needs to be. By replacing the pointers with plain `double`s the shown code will be half its current size. No need to have a copy constructor. No need to have an assignment operator (one was missing). No opportunities for making simple bugs, like attempting to delete a null pointer. This kind of a bug is called "pointless use of pointers".

Comment: The constructor doesn't set the class member variables to point to new doubles; it defines two new local variables that have the same names, and sets the local variables to point to new doubles, leaving the member variables alone.

Comment: I know there is no need for the pointers, it's just the assignment that requires them. Would it be better to use plain `double`  in the `class complex` and then use pointers to objects of that class?

Comment: @DragosPolifronie *"Would it be better to [...]"* -- that depends on your assignment, as your assignment is the only reason to use pointers in this context. On the other hand, using plain `double` in `complex` (no pointers anywhere) would allow you to demonstrate the issue you asked about with a simpler example, which is better for a Stack Overflow question. (The issue you asked about has nothing to do with whether or not pointers are involved.)

Comment: thank you all, got a better point of view now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor you don't initialize `p_real` and `p_imaginar`, you declare new variables, which only live within the scope of constructor, and hence get destroyed, resulting in memory leak.

To avoid this I recommend using [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)

```
class complex
{
private:
    double* p_real;
    double* p_imaginar;

public:
    numar_complex():
       p_real(new double(0.0)),
       p_imaginar(new double(0.0))
    {
        cout << "constructor" << endl;
    }

    .
    .
    .
    .
    //the rest
}
```